# laravel "csrf" issue "Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException"

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel I'm getting a "csrf" issue "Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException"

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'guest'),function()
{
    Route::get('/user/create',array('uses'=>'UserController@getCreate'));
    Route::get('/user/login',array('uses'=>'UserController@getLogin','as'=>'postCreate'));

    Route::group(array('before'=>'csrf'),function()
    {   
        Route::get('/user/create','UserController@postCreate');
        Route::get('/user/login','UserController@postLogin');
    });
});
```

that is controller

```
class UserController extends BaseController{
public function getCreate()
{
    //return View::make('hello');
    return View::make('user.register');
}
```

that is view

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Register</h1>
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{ URL::route('postCreate')}}">
    <div class="form-gourp">
        <label for="username">Username: </label>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-gourp">
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-gourp">
        <label for="username">confirm Password: </label>
        <input id="cpassword" name="cpassword" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    {{form::token()}}
    <div class="form-gourp">
         <input type="submit" value="register" class="btn btn-default"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I add `{{form::token }}`, it shows the error "Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException"

Comment: just curious: is `form-gourp` the correct classname, or should it be `form-group`?

Comment: Does it generate the correct HTML? If you look at the source in your browser you should see a field of type `hidden` containing the token

Comment: no form-gourp is not correct but correct one is form-group and i have replaced it and thanks for correcting me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong in your routes.

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'csrf'),function()
{   
    Route::get('/user/create','UserController@postCreate');
    Route::get('/user/login','UserController@postLogin');
});
```

Those should be `post`, like the following

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'csrf'),function()
{   
    Route::post('/user/create','UserController@postCreate');
    Route::post('/user/login','UserController@postLogin');
});
```

Read more about CSRF on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and [laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#protecting-routes).

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{ Form::open() }}` and `{{ Form::close() }}` rather than the `<form>` tags

Comment: `Form::token()` should still work though. `Form::open()` is not required to make CSRF tokens work.